# Should UI designer and UX designer work on wireframe together?

Tags: wireframe, team, team-building

if yes, especially what parts should they determine together? (Layout?, grid?, information architecture?)

Answer (score 4):

The UX Designer, in my experience, is responsible for creating wireframes. However, you'll collaborate with everyone on the project team as you do it.

I've worked on fancy sites where the UI designer drives the design, with my push-back to keep it simple, clear, and intuitive. We collaborate on interaction effects and page layouts. (I've never determined a grid myself - that's always been their decision.) They're usually more in touch with the latest interaction techniques. But still I'm the one wireframing, documenting our decisions.

In other cases I'll share my first draft with the devs, UI, project managers, etc. - still collaborating, though I'm driving the initial design process.

You'll collaborate, not just with UI Designers, but the entire product team. (And do user research, of course), but ultimately you'll be the one who creates the wireframe documents.

(Is the UI Designer stepping on your role?)

Comment: No, I just wanted to try to work on sketches that define general layouts in a collaboration with UI Designer and sometimes even with product manager. So sometimes I need another brain to touch also onto wireframe. I don't know exactly which way works better but I'm trying when I need to do something different than current situation. It's also really good to hear different experiences.

Comment: That sounds great. I often get into sketching sessions with the visual designer and a whiteboard. Do whatever helps you make the best design decisions!

Answer (score 3):

If they're the same person - which is often the case - then yes, they should definitely work together. But even that is no guarantee of cooperation.

Comment: Straight over the head!